# is it possible control click together with pixel search to work in autohotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

I'm having trouble to control click i'm trying to simulate control click without moving mouse, but i always get error when i run is there something wrong in my code.

```
PixelSearch, X, Y, 0, 0, 1292, 747, 0x00FF00, 0, fast
        if(ErrorLevel=0) 
        sleep, 100
        ControlClick, %X% %Y%, form1, Left, 1
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things you've missed.

First, [If Statements](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IfExpression.htm) only execute the line beneath them. If you have more than 1 line of code, you have to put it in curly braces. It's called [A Block/Blocking (Multiple Lines of Code Inside Braces)](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Block.htm)

Second, your [ControlClick](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlClick.htm) syntax is wrong. If you're passing coordinates, you have to put x and y in front of them so controlclick knows they're coords.

Incorrect:
`ControlClick, %X% %Y%`

Correct:
`ControlClick, x%X% x%Y%`

Third, if you look at your code, you have `Left` where WinText is supposed to be.
Syntax for [ControlClick](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlClick.htm):
`ControlClick [, Control-or-Position, WinTitle, WinText , WhichButton, ClickCount, Options, ExcludeTitle, ExcludeText]`

You can't assume AHK knows `Left` is for the button. You have to tell it to skip that field by putting a comma there to indicate the field is blank. That way it knows to skip wintext and treat Left as the `WhichButton` field.

Incorrect:
`ControlClick, %X% %Y%, form1, Left`

Correct:
`ControlClick, %X% %Y%, form1,, Left`

Put it all together, and you have this:

```
PixelSearch, X, Y, 0, 0, 1292, 747, 0x00FF00, 0, fast
    if (ErrorLevel = 0){
        Sleep, 100
        ControlClick, x%X% y%Y%, form1, , Left, 1
    }
```

Let me know if that solves your problem.

Edit: Apparently this didn't fix your issue. I'm going to bet your controlclick and the info you're passing it are the problem.

Make sure you define [CoordMode](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/CoordMode.htm) at the beginning of the script. You need to set it to fullscreen or relative.

Next, don't use a window's title for [WinTitle](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm) unless there's a good reason to. Instead of form1, use something like `ahk_exe chrome.exe`. It's much more reliable.

```
#SingleInstance, Force
CoordMode, Pixel, Screen
return

F1::
    PixelSearch, X, Y, 0, 0, 1292, 747, 0x00FF00, 0, fast
    if (ErrorLevel = 0){
        Sleep, 100
        ControlClick, x%X% y%Y%, ahk_exe yourExeName.exe, , Left, 1
    }
return
```

What program/site/game are you using this for?

Comment: thank you, however it doesnt click in coordinates where the x y of pixelsearch located.. it just click on my current mouse position :(

Comment: Have you actually tested the code? The problem with ControlClick is that it only works with the Coordmode Window. Even if you set CoordMode, Pixel, Window, the pixelsearch function will not get the correct coordinates that match the coordinates that ControlClick uses. Try it, the clicks will not be at the correct spot. Using "Click" or MouseClick will work, but ControlClick is required if you don't want the mouse to move and take away focus. You could use WinActivate to restore the previous window, but this becomes annoying when you have to do a click every 5~10 seconds.